# indent error in python while using if statements inside for loop

Tags: python

I used the following code:

```
for item in users_dict['items']:
    sl_no = sl_no + 1
    user_id_pass = item['user_id']
    account_id_pass = item['account_id']
    Name_pass = item['display_name']

    if 'age' in item:
        age_pass = item['age']
    else:
        age_pass = 0

    stack_link_pass = item['link']
    user_type_pass = item['user_type']
    Location_pass = item['location']

    if 'website_url' in item:
        website_link_pass = item['website_url']
    else:
        website_link_pass = 'NA'
```

I am getting this error:

```
 user_id_pass = item['user_id']
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

please help me out

Comment: Mixed tabs and spaces?

Comment: Check for spaces and tabs. Use only either of one uniformly.

Comment: There's a tab in front at the start of this line. Don't mix tabs and spaces. It is recommended to use four spaces for each indent level.

Comment: Thanks all. I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see that all your lines are indented with the correct amount of spaces, please check that your using either tabs or spaces to indent.

For example you may have run into this situation:

```
    {4 spaces}sl_no = sl_no + 1
    {--1 tab-}user_id_pass = item['user_id']
    {4 spaces}account_id_pass = item['account_id']
```

Comment: Great to know! :) Would you mind marking this as the answer if it's the case?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can only use one or the other, tabs or spaces, to indent your code. Since tabs and spaces are encoded differently, the interpreter can't tell where your if statement ends. Backspace over all of your indentations, then just tab or space every line the number of indents you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

To Enhance it more for someone who gets into this situation. In your most widely used code editors. [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/).

Type a sequence "Ctrl+Shift+P" a command box will open

In that type "Indentation: Convert to Spaces" or similarly "Indentation: Convert to Tabs".
It will manage all the tabs and spaces and convert them to a uniform type.
Correct the formatting and you are good to go.

[image]